# Can I buy Keisei train tickets with international debit card?

Tags: japan, tokyo

I want to take Keisei line service from Narita airport terminal 2. Will I be able to use my international debit card to pay for the ticket?

Comment: I changed the title, as there are other subway lines in Tokyo operated by different companies.

Comment: I changed the title because Narita is not in Tokyo and also "Keisei line" doesn't exist (Keisei is a company, which operates several lines).

Comment: if you are a foreigner to Japan, you may want to tell your bank you will be in Japan. Some bank has the policy to block payment from unexpected places.

Answer (score 9):

According to the Keisei website [FAQ](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/us/faq/index.php):

> **Can I use a credit card to purchase tickets?**
>
> Major credit cards are accepted only for purchase of a Skyliner ticket (special limited express ticket) or a combined base fare and Skyliner ticket. All other tickets must be purchased in cash using Japanese yen.

This means you can use your card only if you take the expensive faster Skyliner. If you take any of the slower options, you'll have to use cash.

As for which cards are accepted, the [Keisei website](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/us/skyliner/purchase.php) lists the following:

- Visa
- Mastercard
- JCB
- American Express
- Diners Club
- Union Pay (only at the ticket office)
- Discovery (only at the ticket office)

It says *credit card*, but if your debit card is under any of those brands, it should theoretically also work.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an Apple iPhone 8 or X and/or an Apple Watch 3 or 4, then you can get the mobile [Suica](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/suica/id1156875272?mt=8) application on your phone or watch and load it up with cash from your debit card using the Suica App.

Then you can use your iPhone or Apple Watch as your transit pass for local lines such as the Keisei (non-Skyliner), subways, and JR lines. The Suica App is one of the few ways to reload cash onto a Suica card using a credit card. Suica and Apple don’t charge any fees for doing this but you should check to see if your bank will charge a fee for a foreign transaction.  This is a very handy way to navigate Tokyo (or almost all of Japan, since almost all trains and subways in Japan are compatible with Suica).

There's also two [Google/Android Suica apps](https://www.jreast.co.jp/mobilesuica/googlepay/index.html), although I'm not as familiar with them but it looks like they are similar to the Apple iOS version. Unfortunately, JR doesn't have any information in English but there are other websites that describe how to use them.

Comment: Would you happen to know if the Suica app charges any additional fees for loading money from an international debit card?

Comment: @Korak Suica doesn’t but your bank might.

Comment: Is this valid for all versions of those iPhone models? I remember that at some point it only worked in the Japanese version (there are often several versions for each iPhone model for different markets).